# How to make a dynamic price view for checkout

Tags: php, html, ajax, dynamic, transactions

I am currently setting up a checkout for my website. I have a product that I offer options that vary in price and I'd like to have a price preview at the end before the customer decides to pay. I have a checkout modal and ideally I'd want to have the price preview reflect the final price of the product after everything is taken into account. The math is done server side on php, how do I echo or display the variables back into the html page without reloading after pressing a button?

```
    <?php
//sets price based on options selected//
$ord_type_explode =  explode('|',$_POST['ord_type']);
$base_price = $ord_type_explode[1];

$item_options_explode = explode('|',$_POST['item_options']);
$options_add = $item_options_explode[1];

$quantity_select_explode = explode('|',$_POST['quantity_select']);
$quantity_multiplier = $quantity_select_explode[1];

$final_price = ($base_price + $options_add) * $quantity_multiplier;

echo $final_price;



?>
```

Comment: You will need to use AJAX. You can do it using whatever javascript library you want (jQuery, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This is typically performed through an [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Here is a simplistic GET and POST example to help you wrap your head around it.

Get:

```
    var url = 'mypage.php';
    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {

            //Response text
            console.log( xhr.responseText );
        }
    };

    xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
    xhr.send();
```

Post:

```
    var url = 'mypage.php';
    var sendData = 'a=1&b=2'
    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {

            //Response text
            console.log( xhr.responseText );
        }
    };
    xhr.open( "POST", url, true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    xhr.send( sendData );
```

There are also many javascript libraries that offer this type of functionality, see [List of Ajax frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#JavaScript)

Once you have the `xhr.responseText` you can then handle this text however it is best to do based on the response the page is giving back. For example if it is sending a message that says "Success" then you could take the `xhr.responseText` and populate an element with it with [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

There are numerous ways to do this. The question no longer becomes about ajax now, but on how to handle strings in javascript at this point, and this can be researched comfortably through google such as "How to put text into element".

Comment: so this takes the values passed from the html inputs into php, how do I take the resulting data and put it back into my html?

Comment: Edited to answer that query. Happy Programming!